# Add SQL database value in email body

Tags: c#, sql, email, foreach

This is my emailinfo table

```
>         ID  EMAIL                               CREDIT
>         -----------------------------------  ----------
>          1  emal1@gmail.com                      2500
>          2  email2@gmail.com                     13500
>          3  email3@hotmail.com                   3750
>          4  email4@outlook.com                   11700
>          5  email5@outlook.com                   1200
>          6  email6@yahoo.com                     1997
>          7  email7@yahoo.com                     179
>          8  emal8@gmail.com                      10
```

i need to be sent mail to each email address for inform her credit value  using following Body line:

```
Email Body:Dear User your credit value: 2500
```

when i have execute below the code each email address received multiple email such 1st email received 8 mail and 2nd email received 7 mail 3rd email received 6 mail , how can i avoid received multiple email or how can send mail easily with  out any error following code:

```
 MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        message.Subject = "Employee Access ";
        message.From = new MailAddress("xyz@gmail.com");
        var fromAddress = "zxy@gmail.com";
        const string fromPassword="password";
        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        {
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        }
        OleDbCommand cmd = null;
        OleDbCommand cmd2 = null;
        string queryString = "select id,email,credit from emailinfo";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider = OraOLEDB.Oracle.1; Data Source = orcl; Password=bdipf;User ID = human; unicode=true"))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString);
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            adapter.Dispose();
        }
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress(dataRow[2].ToString());
            StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
            if (!message.To.Contains(to))
            {
                message.To.Add(to);
              message.Body = "Dear User your credit value: " + dataRow[2].ToString();
                smtp.Send(message);continue
            }
        }
```

Comment: Check what is there in datatable by debugging, and check if there are duplicate rows, This problem seems easily resolve by debugging.

Comment: i have also debug step by step, but i can not  control loop , the loop remember previous  row and send mail previous and next row

Comment: First off, please use field names not [2] for the fields, you can thank me later :-)  Second thing, and the answer, is you are creating the message OUTSIDE your for loop... I'd fix that.

Comment: all ready check user field name but not  fount solution , i need only one time send  email , my problem email had sent multiple time ,

Comment: Every loop you add another email address to `message`. You should clear the addresses before adding the `to` address.

Comment: @Crowcoder would provide example please.

Comment: Below code is responsible for the error, probably this if condition is not working properly for you and adding the same email id multiple time.  if (!message.To.Contains(to)) {
                message.To.Add(to);

Comment: @MohitSharma that will cause exactly the same problem.

Comment: @MohitSharma  i can ignore the code: if (!message.To.Contains(to)) { message.To.Add(to)

Comment: You just need to : `message.To.Clear();`, then do everything else.

Comment: @Crowcoder  where i put the code?

Comment: You just need to add the message.To.Clear(); just above the if(!message.To.Contains(to)). You can remove this if condition also as list will be clear and will not contains any matching and will be true always.

Comment: lot of thanks @Crowcoder and Mohit Sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution is, you can create MailMessage object in foreach loop just like below code

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
       {
           smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
           smtp.EnableSsl = true;
           smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
           smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
           smtp.Timeout = 20000;
       }

       OleDbCommand cmd = null;
       OleDbCommand cmd2 = null;
       string queryString = "select id,email,credit from emailinfo";
       using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider = OraOLEDB.Oracle.1; Data Source = orcl; Password=bdipf;User ID = human; unicode=true"))
       {
           OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
           connection.Open();
           cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString);
           cmd.Connection = connection;
           OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
           adapter.Fill(dataTable);
           adapter.Dispose();
       }
       foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
       {

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
       message.Subject = "Employee Access ";
       message.From = new MailAddress("xyz@gmail.com");
       var fromAddress = "zxy@gmail.com";
       const string fromPassword="password";
               message.To.Add(new MailAddress(dataRow[1].ToString()););
             message.Body = "Dear User your credit value: " + dataRow[2].ToString();
               smtp.Send(message);continue
           }
       }
```

> You can also do the minor change in your existing code ang can clear the message.To list with below code

```
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows) {
 MailAddress to = new MailAddress(dataRow[1].ToString());
message.To.clear();
message.To.Add(to);
 message.Body = "Dear User your credit value: " + dataRow[2].ToString();
smtp.Send(message);
continue;
 }
```